# Is ergodic in mean a property defined only for WSS stochastic processes?

Tags: ergodic, stochastic

I understand the definition of a random process $X(t)$ being ergodic in mean (first-order ergodic) is that the expectation of the sample mean $<u_X>_T=\frac{1}{T} \int_{\frac{-T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} X_w(t)dt $ should converge to the ensemble mean as $T \rightarrow \infty$. Can we define ergodic in mean property for processes which do not have constant mean.

I know that the property of being ergodic in ACF, second-order ergodic, requires WSS assumption.

My question is motivated by the fact that the requirement of WSS is not given in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process) article describing ergodic process but used in the example illustrating the same.

Comment: If the mean _function_ $\mu_X(t)$ is _not_ a constant, what number should the time-average of the realization $X_w(t)$ of the process converge _to?_

Comment: @DilipSarwate : Yes, you are right. My oversight was the fact that a process with constant mean does not imply WSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time average is defined over a time interval, T which will always result in a constant value. Keeping this constraint in mind, ensemble mean is always forced to be constant for satisfying the condition of ergodicity.